# How to get drawn element height before it's displayed? Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am trying to adjust the height for UITableViewCell.

My cell contains another view, this view will draw text and display it in the cell.

However, the text height may vary, and i will only be able to figure it out after the call to drawRect is made (in the embedded sub view).

Is there any way to figure out the height of the view before it is displayed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as you know the font, the width of the view drawing the text, and if necessary, the line break mode, then you could use either:
`sizeWithFont:

sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:

sizeWithFont:constrainedToSize:lineBreakMode:`

Comment: It is not a string actually, the text is drawn with CGraphics.

Comment: Regardless, it's still text you're drawing, said text will be a string.  Also, [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3182709/quartz-2d-core-graphics-what-is-the-right-way-to-draw-some-text) indicates the different methods of drawing a string, the answer is quite informative too

Comment: Thank you, i use a library that draws the text in some complex way to support custom fonts on ios (the IOS seems to ignore custom fonts for some languages). So this solution doesn't work in my situation. I solved the problem by drawing the same text twice, one to the get the height and another draw to display in on screen. I accepted your answer and i wish i was able to vote up (low reputation since i am new here).

Answer (score 0):

Well finally i find out how to do it, i guess it is not the best way but it works.

I implemented a method that draws everything again and return the height of the drawn text immediately. Now actually i have to draw the text twice, one to get its height and another to display it on screen!